# Batch: Escape array in if-block

Tags: arrays, batch-file, cmd, escaping

I'm trying to check if files from an array exists. The array and the loop are working fine, but the `if exists`-line gives a syntaxerror. I tried different variations (`%%list[%x%]%%`, `list[%x%]`, `%%list[%%x%%]%%`), but none of them works.

**Question:** Why is the `if exists %%list[%x%]%%` not working, but the `call echo Check file: %%list[%x%]%%` works?

*Hint: I use this kind of "loop", because I want that the coded hasn't to be changed if the size of the array changes.*

```
set list[0]="C:\file_a.txt"
set list[1]="C:\file_b.txt"
set list[2]="C:\file_c.txt"

set "found=0"
set "notfound=0"
set "x=0"
:SymLoop
if defined list[%x%] (

    call echo Check file: %%list[%x%]%%

    if exists %%list[%x%]%% (
        set /a "found+=1"
    ) else (
        set /a "notfound+=1"
    )

    set /a "x+=1"
    GOTO :SymLoop
)
echo %found%/%x% file found. %notfound% files missing!
PAUSE
```

**Solved:** The problem was the missing "Delayed Expansion" and in addition a typo (exists instead of exist).

Comment: `if exists %%list[%x%]%%` cannot work as you need an additional layer of expansion; `call echo %%list[%x%]%%` works, because `call` introduces such a layer; `call if ...` does not work though, because `if` is a command that is recognised by the command interpreter before `call`; so the only solution is to use [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). Ah, and put quotes in: `if exists "!list[%x%]!"`...

Comment: By the way, you do not need to use a slow `goto` loop, you could create a loop like `for /F "delims=" %%x in ('set list[') do ( ... )`, which loops through all array elements (given that there is no other variable whose name begin with `list[`)...

Comment: @aschipfl - or simply `for /l` can be used and not worrying what other variables could exist.

Comment: @npocmaka but with `for /l` I had to define the length of the array in the loop. That's what I wanted to prohibit.

Comment: @npocmaka, `for /L` requires the array size to be known. To make sure no disturbing variables exist, the following code could be placed before assigning the array: `for /L "delims==" %%x in ('set list[') do set "%%x="`

Comment: This management is fully explained at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set list[0]="C:\file_a.txt"
set list[1]="C:\file_b.txt"
set list[2]="C:\file_c.txt"

set "found=0"
set "notfound=0"
set "x=0"
:SymLoop
if defined list[%x%] (

    echo Check file: !list[%x%]!

    if exist !list[%x%]! (
        set /a "found+=1"
    ) else (
        set /a "notfound+=1"
    )

    set /a "x+=1"
    GOTO :SymLoop
)
echo %found%/%x% file found. %notfound% files missing!
PAUSE
```

Comment: This results in `"!list[0]!" syntactically cannot be used at this position`

Comment: @netblognet - you are getting this as an error message?

Comment: Yes. The `echo Check file: !list[%x%]!` works without problems, but the `if exists !list[%x%]!` produces the above written error messages.

Comment: @netblognet - check my edit. It should be `if exist` but not `if exists`

Comment: @npocmaja That was the error. I'm feeling really stupid, right now. Thanks for your help!